# Insert into (select )

Tags: sql

I have a table named songInPlaylist, and I want to add a new row when it is not exist, this table is linked to two other tables song and playlist.
songInPlaylist contains to feilds: songId, playlistId (all of this feilds is foreign key to other two tables).

I started writing this code

```
insert into songinplaylist
(select songid, playlistid
from songinplaylist
where songid = 1 and playlistid = 10)
```

I want to add a new row `(songid -> 1, playlistid -> 10)`
when this row isn't exist in the table.

Comment: Have you researched how to insert a record in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `WHERE` to check if the row already exists or not:

```
INSERT INTO songinplaylist (songid, playlistid)
SELECT 1, 10 FROM dual
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM songinplaylist
    WHERE
      songid = 1
      AND
      playlistid = 10
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard ANSI insert syntax. check it out

```
insert into songinplaylist
(songid, playlistid) values (1,10);
```

Comment: note : you can omit the list of column `(songid, playlistid)` if the values you are inserting are all the columns of the table given in the same order as the definition